# mySQL Trigger: Setting empty to NULL, doesn't work on last column

Tags: mysql, triggers

With your help already I have succeeded in setting a trigger that will set 3 of the 4 primary key columns in my local load file to `NULL` if they contain an empty string.

However the issue is that it seems to be ignoring the 4th, and is not replacing the empty string with a `NULL`, which is allows empty "sex" column to be input into database.

The only difference I can see is that the "sex" column happens to be the final column in the csv load file. Any ideas how to get this one working? Tried `elseif` as well was just changing it up by doing multiple if statements. Nothing seems to work.

Trigger code:

```
BEGIN
  if new.year = '' then
     set new.year = null;
     end if;
  if new.event_id = '' then
     set new.event_id = null;
     end if;
  if new.round = '' then
     set new.round = null;
     end if;
  if new.sex = '' then
     set new.sex = null;
     end if;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

File: `/path/to/file/test_file.csv`

```bsh
2000|1|1|
2001|2|1|M
2002|3|1|F
2003|4|2|
```

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `bi_trg_test`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;

CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `year` VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_id` VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT NULL,
    `round` VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sex` CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `bi_trg_test` BEFORE INSERT ON `test_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`year` = '' THEN
        SET NEW.`year` := NULL;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.`event_id` = '' THEN
        SET NEW.`event_id` := NULL;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.`round` = '' THEN
        SET NEW.`round` := NULL;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.`sex` = '' THEN
        SET NEW.`sex` := NULL;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/test_file.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE `test_table`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    -> (`year`, `event_id`, `round`, `sex`);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    -> `id`,
    -> `year`,
    -> `event_id`,
    -> `round`,
    -> `sex`
    -> FROM
    -> `test_table`;
+----+------+----------+-------+------+
| id | year | event_id | round | sex  |
+----+------+----------+-------+------+
|  1 | 2000 | 1        | 1     | NULL |
|  2 | 2001 | 2        | 1     | M    |
|  3 | 2002 | 3        | 1     | F    |
|  4 | 2003 | 4        | 2     | NULL |
+----+------+----------+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another option without using triggers:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `bi_trg_test`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `test_table`;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/test_file.csv'
    INTO TABLE `test_table`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    (@`year`, @`event_id`, @`round`, @`sex`)
    SET 
        `year` = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@`year`)) = 0, NULL, @`year`),
        `event_id` = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@`event_id`)) = 0, NULL, @`event_id`),       
        `round` = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@`round`)) = 0, NULL, @`round`),       
        `sex` = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@`sex`)) = 0, NULL, @`sex`);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    -> `id`,
    -> `year`,
    -> `event_id`,
    -> `round`,
    -> `sex`
    -> FROM
    -> `test_table`;
+----+------+----------+-------+------+
| id | year | event_id | round | sex  |
+----+------+----------+-------+------+
|  1 | 2000 | 1        | 1     | NULL |
|  2 | 2001 | 2        | 1     | M    |
|  3 | 2002 | 3        | 1     | F    |
|  4 | 2003 | 4        | 2     | NULL |
+----+------+----------+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```